# VSCode: 'router-outlet' is not a known element angular 10

Tags: angular, templates, visual-studio-code

I've been having this issue where visual studio code has been showing me the following error in html files in Angular.

```
router-outlet' is not a known element:
...
```

The error is not limited to that element. It turns out, every custom HTML element (i.e. referencing any angular component). Also, I'm not getting any error when compiling the code, just in the editor. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything related to this issue.

Versions:

Angular - 10.0.8

VSCode - 1.55.2

Comment: Are you getting this error only on VSCode or even in console tab while running the application?

Comment: The error is just in vscode and not in the application

Comment: Do you have the [Angular Template Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) installed, it might fix your issue(s)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You're a legend. I've been using Angular for a few years and had this extension installed but I checked again and sure enough, there was an update to the extension which seemed to have fixed the issue. Thanks again